# MYSQL Update all foreign key values

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two identical tables that are located in two identical databases(with different name). I want to merge these two tables, but their primary keys are used in other tables,

these tables look like this:

**Table A**

```
id     column1     column2    column3
___    ________    _______    ________
 1        text        text      text
 2        text        text      text
 3        text        text      text
```

**Table B**

```
id     column1     column2    column3
___    ________    _______    ________
 2        text        text      text
 3        text        text      text
 4        text        text      text
```

**tables that are linked to Table A**

**Link A**

```
id     column1     tableA_ID
___    ________    _______  
 1        text        2     
 2        text        3      
 3        text        4
```

**Link B**

```
id     column1     tableA_ID
___    ________    _______  
 1        text        3     
 2        text        3      
 3        text        2
```

Please note, the tables have identical `id`'s, this means when I do the merge, I have to change the `id`'s of the second table. Remember the *second table's primary keys are used in other tables.*

I wrote this query to merge the two tables:

```
INSERT INTO db_A.`Table_A`(`column2`,`column3`) 
    SELECT `column2`,`column3` FROM db_B.`Table_B`;
```

This query will correctly copy the records of the second table to the first table.

Now I want to also move the data of the tables that are linked with `Table B`, I can use the same query, but now the foreign key will not match, because the `ID` they were linked with has been changed.

How do I update them so that the `ID` will match again?

**NB: I do not have the ON UPDATE CASCADE constraint on those tables**

I hope this make sense, I will try to improve this question so that everyone understands it.

**Database Info**

```
Type  : MySQL
Engine: MyISAM
```

Comment: Update IDs to unique ranges, merge.

Comment: You mean i should first update all the ID's of `Table_B` and its references before the merge? mmm.... how come I've never thought of that, nice idea

Comment: You should switch to InnoDB.  Until then, none of the `FOREIGN KEY` answers apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to update the `TableB`'s `ID`s to unique range and then do the merge. If your foreign keys are properly set to cascade the change, your database will stay consistent through this operation.

You don't need to do any changes to the database schema this way, so there is no point in time when the data is not calid. You can also be sure that the IDs won't clash. Easiest way to find unique values is to take the maximum of the `ID` in `TableA` and add that to the `ID`s in `TableB`.

Comment: _"I do not have the ON UPDATE CASCADE constraint on those tables"_

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Sorry, missed that. I'd suggest changing that to be sure everything's update properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to each table with foreign keys related to `TableB.id` in second database temporary:

```sql
ALTER TABLE db2.other_tables_with_fk DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_to_TableB;

ALTER TABLE db2.other_tables_with_fk
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_to_TableB FOREIGN KEY (TableB_id)
    REFERENCES TableB(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and afterwards use the trick in [Sami's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554229/2721611) and then remove temporary changes like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE db2.other_tables_with_fk DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_to_TableB;

ALTER TABLE db2.other_tables_with_fk
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_to_TableB FOREIGN KEY (TableB_id)
    REFERENCES TableB(id);
```

Then your second database will be ready to merge with the first one.

---

For **MyISM** or situations that `CASCADE` is not supported by engine you can simulate it manually by defining [**Triggers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON TableB
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE other_tables_with_fk1 SET TableB_id = NEW.id WHERE TableB_id = OLD.id
    UPDATE other_tables_with_fk2 SET TableB_id = NEW.id WHERE TableB_id = OLD.id
    ...
END
```

---

Even if triggers are not available you can simply increase id number of rows in second database by some custom amount(any amount greater than max row id which used in first database) in all tables including foreign key parent table at a same time:

```sql
UPDATE TableB t SET t.id = (t.id + 10000);
UPDATE related_table_1 t SET t.TableB_id = (t.TableB_id + 10000);
UPDATE related_table_2 t SET t.TableB_id = (t.TableB_id + 10000);
...
```

And then you can merge those databases.

Answer (score 3):

my suggestion were:

1. you drop the foreign key constraint of *LinkA* in *database1*
2. increase the foreign key of the *TableA:id* AND *LinkA:tableA_ID* (the best way were with a join) by lets say 1000 (or how much rows you have in *database2*)
3. add the constraint again (optional)
4. import *TableA* and **then** *LinkA* to *database2* from *database1*.

If you need more help, just ask.

Best Regards

====================================

Update. Example for the update of the ids:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A, Link_A 
SET
    Table_A.id = Table_A.id + 1000, 
    Link_A.id  = Link_A.tableA_ID + 1000, 
FROM
    Table_A JOIN Link_A 
ON 
    Table_A.id = Link_A.tableA_ID
```

Comment: Is your query valid? I mean I see `Update` and `From` in one query

Comment: Hi Luthando, I don't have MySQL to explicitly test the query.
But an equivalent query worked for me with MS SQLServer.
And look [here, example at the bottom][1]


  [1]: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/update.php

Comment: It's better not to use joins because in joins we could miss some records(null records in RIGHT or LEFT side of join) specially when having two or more relations to same foreign table.

Comment: @Raymon: Yeah, I could agree with you... in the case of complex query and nullable columns. But here we're talking about IDs

Comment: No I was not meaning about nullable columns. If you test it by 2 or more tables you'll get the point. Specially for rows which are not used in child tables but exist in parent table and it will be more complicated when number of child tables increase. Just using a separate update for each table is safer.

Answer (score 2):

If both db are identical, I believe you should name it `db_B.Table_A` not `db_B.Table_B` to avoid confusion..but for now I go along with it

```
--get delta id, use biggest id from db_A and db_B 
--to avoid failure because of updating to existing primary key

SELECT @dbBMax := MAX(id) FROM db_B.`Table_B`;
SELECT @dbAMin := MIN(id), @dbAMax := MAX(id) FROM db_A.`Table_A`;
SET @DeltaID := IF(@dbBMax > @dbAMax, @dbBMax, @dbAMax) - @dbAMin + 1;

--drop constraint
ALTER TABLE db_A.`Link_A` DROP FOREIGN KEY `constraint_name_A`;
ALTER TABLE db_A.`Link_B` DROP FOREIGN KEY `constraint_name_B`;

--update ids
UPDATE db_A.`Table_A` SET id = id + @DeltaID;
UPDATE db_A.`Link_A` SET tableA_ID = tableA_ID + @DeltaID;
UPDATE db_A.`Link_B` SET tableA_ID = Link_A.tableA_ID + @DeltaID;

--merge tables 
--assume id is auto-increment, don't use auto-increment value, 
--so id manually inserted
INSERT INTO db_A.`Table_A`(`id`, `column1`, `column2`,`column3`) 
SELECT `id`, `column1`, `column2`,`column3` FROM db_B.`Table_B`;

--assume id is auto-increment, use it, don't insert manually     
INSERT INTO db_A.`Link_A`(`column1`, `tableA_ID`) 
SELECT `column1`, `tableA_ID` FROM db_B.`Link_A`;

--assume id is auto-increment, use it, don't insert manually     
INSERT INTO db_A.`Link_B`(`column1`, `tableA_ID`) 
SELECT `column1`, `tableA_ID` FROM db_B.`Link_B`;
```

This code may add *big* leap on `id` at `db_B.Table_B` if `db_A.Table_A` have much more data that `db_B.Table_B`..that can be fixed easily before/after merge table..but I think its optional..